# Recaptcha Callback method not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recaptcha

I am trying to have my callback fire once recaptacha i loaded however it won't load the callback.

Taken from https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#example

> ```
>     grecaptcha.render('example3', {
>       'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
>       'callback' : verifyCallback,
>       'theme' : 'dark'
>     });
> ```

In my example I am doing:

```
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': config.recaptcha.id,
            'callback': function(){
                  console.info('something'); 
             }
        });
```

The callback function will never execute. reCacptcha will however load in the page.

Latest version of Chrome

Comment: Make sure your `verifyCallback` is global or else google can't access it.

Comment: Well what about the  anonymous function being passed to it? :/

Comment: That won't work because google needs a named function.